# Link to a Document Content Type not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type

I'm trying to setup a link to a File Share folder using the **Link to a Document** Content Type.

When creating the Link initially I can only use `http://` instead of `file:\\` but can amend the properties afterwards.

I have amended the file path with `file://` within the Edit Properties and the test link option works fine (opens the file explorer window). When saved and used however I get a blank web page and nothing else.

This is on SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Network or local system path using `file` attribute than you should **put one more slash** in it like mentioned below.

**Please use `file:///SHARED/` instead of `file://SHARED/`.**

The path with `file://SHARED/` will always open blank webpage & `file:///SHARED/` will open the explorer with given location.

Comment: Just tried that, it's not worked. When testing the link it pops up with _Cannot find .....:///'SHARED' Make sure the path or Internet address is correct._ And still get the blank page. I've tried it with 4 as well, the test works again but still the blank page.

Comment: Do you want to open the network location or a local drive?

Comment: Its a network drive

Comment: It is working fine on my end. Do you have the sufficient permission on network location?

Comment: I had faced same issue in my past & it is resolved using given solution only. Otherwise you need to use JavaScript code to open it.

Comment: Yeah I have permissions to the folder. Thanks for your help though.